# Large Database causing crashing of the website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have a woocommerce site running on VPS 4GB RAM and has 3 thousand products with a large number of variations.

The database has 57 tables and 1,867,717 rows and 360MB; the wp_postmeta itself has 1,500,000 rows and has the half size of the database.

The database is always crashing. I tried to optimize my database with wp sweep plugin but still, it is crashing.

Is a dedicated server the only solution for me or there is other solution?

Comment: Are you checking your logs? How do you know  'the database is always crashing'? This is probably off topic.

Comment: I'm receiving error establishing a database connection and this what my hosting said.